# Rename image during upload using date and time stamp?

Tags: images, uploads

I am trying to rename images during upload to avoid problems with image file names containig special characters and file names with non-latin characters.

I found this function to [rename images in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788863/rename-image-before-wordpress-upload-it):

```
function sanitize_file_uploads( $file ){
    $file['name'] = sanitize_file_name($file['name']);
    $file['name'] = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]/", "", $file['name']);
    $file['name'] = strtolower($file['name']);
    add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'remove_accents');

    return $file;
}
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'sanitize_file_uploads');
```

It will remove special unaccepted characters, converts name to lowercase, and remove accents. But, for example if image has only non latin characters it will create image file name like this: jpg-width-heigh.jpg (width and height are dimensions of image).

I would like to have image file name based on current date and time like: year-month-day-hour-minute-second.jpg

I know there is plug which can do that [file renaming on upload](https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-renaming-on-upload/), but I do not wish to use plugin just for that.

Does anyone have solution, idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could e.g. check the *filename* and *extension* from the `pathinfo`, after your custom sanitization.

**Example:**

If the *filename* is empty and *extension* non-empty, then add the formatted current time as the filename part:

```
$info = pathinfo( $file['name'] );
if( empty( $info['filename'] ) && ! empty( $info['extension'] ) )
    $file['name'] = sprintf( '%s.%s', current_time( 'Y-m-d-H-i-s' ), $info['extension'] );
```

If the file `áéíú.png` is stripped to `.png` with your custom sanitization, then it would be renamed to `2016-08-14-10-54-07.png`

Note that if you import another such file within the same second, then `wp_unique_filename()` will add -1 to the filename part so it will be renamed to `2016-08-14-10-54-07-1.png`. The third file would get `-2` appended and so on.

Hope you can adjust this further to your needs.

Comment: you're welcome, glad it helped. @AdvancedSEO